# Spotify - Post & Get a Track with C++ / Objective-C

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, spotify

we're developing an iOS application, in which one of its feature is to post a track/playlist from the app to a user's inbox (messages). At first, I attempted to do this with C++, but I'm not seeing any API that would allow me to post a track to a user's inbox:

https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.51/modules.html

So, I resorted to Obj-C to post a track. Here's my code snippet:

```
    [self.connection cancel];

    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.receivedData = data;
    [data release];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://play.spotify.com/browse"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *postData = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"spotify:user:1234567890:playlist:3abcde12345colorQWERTY"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    self.connection = connection;
    [connection release];

    [connection start];
```

I could see the messages from the console that the data were received and the connection were successfully established. So, my guess was that the track URL was successfully pushed to Spotify server (?), but I had no idea where it were pushed to.

So, how do I push a track or a playlist URL to a user's inbox using C++ or Obj-C?

I've been trying to make this work for the whole day yesterday, but I haven't been successful yet. Would any body give me some pointer? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a [requestb.in](http://requestb.in) to make sure you're POSTing the correct payload?

Comment: Why does the language you use to compose a URL request matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`play.spotify.com` is the web player, not an API. `POST`ing to it like that is like `POST`ing to Facebook.com and expecting something to happen.

I'm not sure where you found documentation suggesting you can send requests directly to `play.spotify.com` like that, but a list of the Web API endpoints and their locations can be found [here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/) on the Spotify Developer website. Unfortunately, I don't think there's an API for sending to a user's Inbox just yet.